# Compute component probabilities in EM-algorithm with log densities?

Tags: optimization, normal-distribution, machine-learning, floating-point, clustering

I coded up an implementation of the [EM-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) for Gaussian mixtures. In the E-step I compute, for each row in the data matrix, the probability $p_i$ that it has been drawn from the component $i \in \{1, \dots K\}$. Specifically, for a given row $X_{j, \cdot}$, I compute the densities $d_1, d_2, ..., d_K$ given by each of the mixture components $1, 2, \dots, K$. Then I compute $p_i = d_i / Z$, where $Z=d_1 + \dots + d_K$.

This procedure works for simple examples, but especially for larger number of variables, the densities $d_i$ are often put to exactly zero, because I only have a finite number of floating points on my computer. The natural solution would be to use $\log d_i$, but I do not see how to write $p_i = d_i / Z$ in terms of $\log d_i$. For example, for $K=2$ we have

$$
\log \left [ \frac{d_1}{d_1 + d_2} \right ] 
=
\log \left [ \frac{d_1}{d_2} \right ] - \log \left [ \frac{d_1 + d_2}{d_2} \right ] 
$$

and now I am stuck with the second term on the RHS.

I'd assume there must be a solution to this problem, since I guess any EM implementation runs into this problem.

Comment: You might want to add a couple of tags. As you can see the "Related" posts on the right are not really related. In addition, some users with expertise follow only selected tags and block all other posts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added a few more tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a datapoint $\mathbf x$, you compute the log-densities,
\begin{align} \log d_i & := \log\left(\pi_i \times \mathcal N\left(\mathbf x \mid \mathbf m_i, \mathbf S_i \right) \right) \\ &=  \log \pi_i - \frac 1 2 (\mathbf x -  \mathbf m_i)\mathbf S_i^{-1} (\mathbf x - \mathbf m_i) - \frac 1 2 \log\det\mathbf S_i - \frac D 2 \log (2\pi)\end{align}
for each $i\in \{ 1, \dots, K \}$, where:

- $\pi_i$, the size of the $i^{\rm th}$ cluster as a proportion of the population
- $\mathbf m_i$, the mean of the $i^{\rm th}$ cluster
- $\mathbf S_i$, the variance of the $i^{\rm th}$ cluster

are the cluster parameters computed in your previous M-step, and $D$ is the number of dimensions. (If you use my formula for $\log d_i$, your calculation should be numerically stable.)

Next, you identify the cluster $i_\star$ that gives the highest log-density for the datapoint $\mathbf x$:
$$ i_\star := {\rm argmax}_{i \in \{1, \dots, K\}} \log d_i,$$

and you define the intermediate quantities
$$ \gamma_i := \exp\left(\log d_i - \log d_{i_\star} \right)$$
for each $i \in \{1, \dots, K\}$.

Notice that:

- Each of the $\gamma_i$'s is a floating-point number between $0$ and $1$.
- One of the $\gamma_i$'s (namely, $\gamma_{i_\star}$) is exactly equal to one.

You also compute
$$ Z := \sum_{i=1}^K \gamma_i,$$
which is guaranteed to be a floating-point number between $1$ and $K$.

Finally, the cluster assignment probabilities are given by
$$ p_i = \frac{\gamma_i}{Z}$$
for each $i \in \{1, \dots, K \}$.

This procedure is numerically stable. There is no risk of incurring errors from handling small numbers (or large numbers, for that matter).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only one thing, I assume it should be: $ \gamma_i := \exp\left( \log d_{i_\star} - \log d_i \right)$, right? Otherwise you do not have $\gamma_i \in [0,1] \forall i$.

Comment: @jmb No, I think it should be $\exp(\log d_i - \log d_{i_\star})$. Remember, $\log d_{i_\star}$ is the largest of the $\log d_j$'s. So $\log d_i - \log d_{i_\star} < 0$, and hence $\exp(\log d_i - \log d_{i_\star}) < 1$.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks! One more thing: why are you weighting the likelihoods in the very first step? I think in the E-step we want the likelihood of each point given each model, and to me it seems that the weight should only be in the likelihood of the mixture.

Comment: @jmb We *do* want to weight the likelihoods in the very first step. When deciding which cluster my current datapoint is likely to belong to, I must take into account *two* things: (i) How well does my current datapoint fit a particular cluster, i.e. how big is $\mathcal N (\mathbf x | \mathbf m_i, \mathbf S_i)$? (ii) How big is this cluster in the first place, i.e. how big is $\pi_i$.

Comment: Said another way, $d_i$ is supposed to represent $P(z = i , \mathbf x | \mathbf m_i, \mathbf S_i)$, where $z \in \{1, \dots, K \}$ is the cluster assignment for this datapoint. Now $P(z = i , \mathbf x | \mathbf m_i, \mathbf S_i) = P(z = i) \times P(\mathbf x | \mathbf m_i, \mathbf S_i, z = i) = \pi_i \times \mathcal N(\mathbf x | \mathbf m_i , \mathbf S_i)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for your explanations, this was really helpful!